# Wordpress WebToffee alternatives

Tags: wordpress, csv, ms-access, woocommerce, server

I am planning to use WordPress [WebToffee](https://profiles.wordpress.org/webtoffee/#content-plugins) plugin to setup my online WooCommerce site. The plugin however only supports CSV files. I can easily convert all of my Access Database to CSV but I cannot include images. The problem is that there are more than 1000 images on the database. Is there a WebToffee alternative that can access images. If there are no other alternatives what would be the best option to put all the images online so that I can have the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data can be imported both in CSV and XML files. Images which are present in your database or in any public URL can be easily imported into your site by inserting the image name or image URL in the respective column of the CSV/XML.

[Read more here](https://www.webtoffee.com/woocommerce-import-products-with-images/)